# counter inside awk statement

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to get the number of text occurrence in a file. therefor, I used the following command:

```
grep FAIL $sPath/FTM.FC*$yesterday* |awk -F ":" '{print $7}' | awk '{print $1}' |awk '{if ($1 == "userNotReachable"){cnt++;} ;{print cnt}  };'
```

in first part:

```
 grep FAIL $sPath/FTM.FC*$yesterday* |awk -F ":" '{print $7}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I am filtering the output to get only the one column.. then i check if that column is equals to the searched text "***userNotReachable***" if true then increase the counter, later on i want to print the value of the counter into text file

here is a sample source file content, it is error logs:

```
2019-01-03 19:29:59.923 FAIL RETRY: Failed for request id: 14899507 Cause: userNotReachable Info: <undef> Code: 27,USSD RequestId=14899507 OriginalId=14899507 EventCorrelationId="1211005491|245065451||1546527554000" CreationTime="20190103192959" ResendCount=0 Timestamp=1546527599482 (Thu Jan 03 19:29:59 AFT 2019) State=STATE_SENT SubscriberNumber=708023643 UssdText=Last event was charged 0.04 MB from 1GB Monthly, Remaining data 421.95 MB (Exp 12.01.2019)1500 AFS = 32GB valid 30 Days, Dial *477*32*1#. NumberingPlan=1 Nadi=4 UssdFormat=2
```

i want to get count of several error causes like:

```
userNotReachable
unknown
equipmentFailure
timeout
userBusy
userNotReachable
userUnavailable
```

and print the count of each error into text file

Comment: write the counter to a text file in an `END` clause in awk.

Comment: @Fshamri, you need not to use these many `awk`s and `grep` commands we could do it in single `awk` itself. Please post sample of your input and expected output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: I pasted sample log content in the my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be making a lot of piping here. You can just do it with a single awk:

```
awk -F ":" '/FAIL/ && ($6 ~ / *userNotReachable /) {c++}END{print c}' $sPath/FTM.FC*$yesterday*
```

After the update, you might want to do this:

```
awk '/FAIL/ { match($0,/ Cause: /); n=RSTART+RLENGTH;
              match(substr($0,n)," "); a[substr($0, n,RSTART-1)]++}
     END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}'
```